# Restrict file upload type to only Image

Tags: html, file-upload

I am using a HTML form to upload image files. Now i am using server side validation to allow the file types. But i want to validate it in client side as well. I have seen in some websites which greys out other file types when we are choosing the file. I think that is a cool option. When i was walking through google i found this

```
<input id="my_file_element" type="file" name="file_0" accept="image/*">
```

But with this i am getting "All Files" option so tat i can enable other files as well. I don't need that. No matter what happens the user should be allowed to select only images files from their computer. Do you guys know a way to do this ?

This is what i meant by greying out.
[image]

Comment: I tried it in Firefox and it's working corectly there. What browser are you using?

Comment: You could use javascript to check the extension on the file form. I'd give you some code but I suck at javascript. Maybe jQuery would work, if you prefer that.

Comment: @dotweb:i am using Google Chrome.. in firefox can u use "all files" option and choose other files ?

Comment: @Different55 i am using javascript or jQuery can i stop user from clicking on non image files ?? because thats wat i want.. non image files should be greyed out when they open the file chooser!!

Comment: Yep, I can choose between image files and all files.

Comment: @dotweb:  that is my issue.. the users should be allowed to choose only images not all files..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `accept` attribute is a HTML5 feature and so is unsupported by a lot of browsers.

I'm afraid that, as long as I remember, the only other way to get a better file upload dialog (filetype filters, multiple files...) is to use a Flash object.

Comment: Can you check my edit ?? I have uploaded an image of how it should look. I think they are not using flash here coz the interface is from MAC and not flash. am i rite ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the HTML for image upload, By default it will show image files only in browsing window becauase we have put accept="image/*" . But still we can change it from the dropdown and it will show all files. So the Javascript part validates whether the selected file is an actual image or not.

 <div class="col-sm-8 img-upload-section">
     <input name="image3" type="file" accept="image/*" id="menu_images"/>
     <img id="menu_image" class="preview_img" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </div> 

Here on the change event first we are checking the size of the image. And in the second if condition we are checking whether it is an image file or not.
this.files[0].type.indexOf("image") will be "-1" if it is not an image file.

    document.getElementById("menu_images").onchange = function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        if(this.files[0].size>528385){
            alert("Image Size should not be greater than 500Kb");
            $("#menu_image").attr("src","blank");
            $("#menu_image").hide();  
            $('#menu_images').wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
            $('#menu_images').unwrap();     
            return false;
        }
        if(this.files[0].type.indexOf("image")==-1){
            alert("Invalid Type");
            $("#menu_image").attr("src","blank");
            $("#menu_image").hide();  
            $('#menu_images').wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
            $('#menu_images').unwrap();         
            return false;
        }   
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
            document.getElementById("menu_image").src = e.target.result;
            $("#menu_image").show(); 
        };

        // read the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    };
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.